# Hiding a tab in TabBar?

Tags: c#, maui

I have a TabBar we use for navigation in our app. We create the TabBar in our MainPage.xaml as follows:

```
    <TabBar >
    <ShellContent
        Title="Loading"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoadingPage}"
        Route="MedexPatientAppsV2.Views.LoadingPage"
        Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
        Shell.FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
        />
    <Tab Title="Home" Icon="home">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}" Route="MedexPatientAppsV2.Views.HomePage"  />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title ="Clinic" Icon="clinic">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ClinicPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Benefit" Icon="benefit" IsVisible="{Binding IsTPA}">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:BenefitListPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Bill" Icon="claim">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:BillListPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="MC" Icon="cert">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:McPage}"/>
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

The first page that is displayed to the user is the first ShellContent inside our TabBar, so in this case, LoadingPage would be the first page that is visited. However, doing this means Loading becomes a tab as seen here:

[image]

how would i hide the tab for loading? I've tried setting the property for the ShellContent for LoadingPage isVisible as false, but doing this means the user will no longer navigate to the loadingpage, which i dont want because this is where we check if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74269299/login-page-for-net-maui, I recommend my answer, but the accepted answer does work. Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74597909/net-maui-implementing-logout-functionality. There are others as well, just search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method is to create a Observable Property and bind it to the property `IsVisible="{Binding IsLoadingVisible}"` of the pages you want to hide or display.

```
public partial class TestViewModel: ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    bool isLoadingVisible= true;
}
```

Then create a new instance of it and set `BindingContext` for `AppShell.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
     public static TestViewModel viewModel;

    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        viewModel = new TestViewModel();
        this.BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
    <TabBar >
    <ShellContent
    Title="Loading"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoadingPage}" IsVisible="{Binding IsLoadingVisible}"

    />
    <Tab Title="Home" Icon="home" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"   />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title ="Clinic" Icon="clinic">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ClinicPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Benefit" Icon="benefit" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:BenefitListPage}" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

Once you want to change the visibility of your page, please change the value of `IsLoadingVisible`.

```
 AppShell.viewModel.IsLoadingVisible = false;
```

Note:

1.Rember to install [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/) package.

For more information, please check: [ObservableObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject).

2.This problem is very similar to the Login page of AppShell, you can also refer to thread: [What's the correct way to implement login page in Shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54586621/whats-the-correct-way-to-implement-login-page-in-xamarin-shell).Though it is a xamarin case, but the implementation process is basically the same.

You can refer to solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57348505/10308336.

Comment: link you provided was what i needed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**
Get the `LoadingPage` out of your Shell definition and assign it to the MainPage. After checking the login state, set MainPage to either `AppShell` or `LoginPage`

**Long Version**
In the past, we've tackled this challenge in a manner not officially endorsed by Microsoft, as mentioned by the .NET MAUI Product Manager during a [community standup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQbJPm1VBkg). Our approach involved removing the `LoadingPage` from the shell and dynamically setting the `MainPage` based on user authentication status.

Here’s what our code looks like in App.xaml.cs:

```
MainPage = new LoadingPage();
```

Within `LoadingPage`, we check whether the user is logged in. Depending on the authentication status, we then switch the `MainPage` accordingly: if the user is logged in, we set `MainPage` to `AppShell`. If not, we set it to the `LoginPage`.

So in your LoadingPage you would have something like this

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
{
   // check if the user is logged in
   if(userIsLoggedIn)
   {
      Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
   }
   else
   {
      Application.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();
   }
}
```

Similar Code goes into your LoginPage after the user entered working credentials.

Even though it's not recommended to set `MainPage` multiple times, it works quite well for us (at least in this scenario).

In our production apps, we are using a Message based approach using the [MVVM Toolkit Messenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger) to centralize setting the MainPage. You can see more in a sample I contributed to here:

[Miracle List MAUI Sample Application on GitHub](https://github.com/HSchwichtenberg/MiracleListNET/blob/MAUI/src/MiracleList_MAUI/App.xaml.cs)

The code looks like this:

`App.xaml.cs`
public partial class App : Application
{
private readonly IServiceProvider services;

```
    public App(IServiceProvider services, IMessenger messenger)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.services = services;
        messenger.Register<UserLoggedInMessage>(this, (r,m) => {
            ShowAppShell();
        });

        messenger.Register<UserLoggedOutMessage>(this, (r, m) => {
            ShowLogin();
        });

        ShowLogin();
    }

    private void ShowLogin()
    {
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(services.GetService<LoginPage>());
    }

    private void ShowAppShell()
    {
        MainPage = services.GetService<AppShell>();
    }
}
```

`UserLoggedInMessage`:
public class UserLoggedInMessage : ValueChangedMessage
{
public UserLoggedInMessage(string user) : base(user)
{
}
}

`UserLoggedOutMessage`:
public class UserLoggedOutMessage : ValueChangedMessage
{
public UserLoggedOutMessage(string user) : base(user)
{
}
}

`LoginViewModel`

```
private void Login()
{
   // other code

   // check if credentials are valid
   if(credentialsAreValid)
   {
      messenger.Send(new UserLoggedInMessage(Username));
   }
}
```

And then in MauiProgram.cs, we register everything in the ServiceCollection:

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit();
            });

        RegisterServices(builder.Services);
        return builder.Build();
    }

    private static void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<App>();
        services.AddSingleton<IMessenger>(WeakReferenceMessenger.Default);
        services.AddScoped<AppShell>();
        services.AddScoped<AppShellViewModel>();
        services.AddScoped<MainPage>();


        // Register View and ViewModel using MAUI Community Toolkit 
        services.AddScoped<LoginPage, LoginPageViewModel>();
    }
```

Of course there's no need to use a message based approach. That's just what works fine for us to make the code a bit more maintanable and readable.

Answer (score 1):

This LoadingPage has no place in your TabBar.

There are more than one reasons to move it, but the two main problems you will face:

1. You will have hard time redrawing the bar, if you decide to dynamically add/remove items to it (there was a bug in MAUI, not sure if it is even fixed)
2. You will have hard time preventing the user to click on other tabs, and navigate away from it.

You can place it before the TabBar, as separate item, and it will be the first ContentPage that is being loaded, and you can navigate to the first Tab, once the LoadingPage has done its work.

There are quite a lot "implementing login" questions for MAUI.

I want to point out something important.

You do **NOT** want this in your program: `MainPage = new LoadingPage()`

You want to use the Dependency Injection, and avoid manual construction of pages.

Using shell, and navigating with "//" clears the navigation stack. So the user will be unable to go back to the LoadingPage. And if you want to log him out, you can navigate from the TabBar, with "//LoadingPage", to lock him out again.

There is no need for manual construction.